# How to connect an intent to a method

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I don't see how to specify the function that an intent filter calls or how to get the arguments (data) from that intent.

For instance, say in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file I have the following:

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
     <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

A user goes to http://example.com/some-end-point - an app-chooser pops up and the user chooses my app (let's call it MyApp).  So what gets called within MyApp and how do I get the arguments, in this case `/some-end-point` that was called?

> How do I specify what block of code this intent refers to ... Do I
>   register it within the Java code or do I specify it in the XML?
>
> Sorry for the basic question but I've been unable to find this after
>   quite a bit of searching and going through the sample code.
>
> Maybe I have a fundamentally wrong assumption of the programmatic
>   model used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this was non-obvious.  Inside of the main `onCreate` below, there's a global `getIntent()` that can be accessed which isn't determined by a pass-by-anything.

Let's establish more context by showing a larger `ActivityMain.xml`

```
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The `android:name` here is the main link over to the `MainActivity` class inside of `MainActivity.java` which is usually part of the default boilerplate (as in the templated code that is created for you when you start a new project).

Within this class there's a method `onCreate` that gets called following the [life-cycle rules](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) (in simple terms; when you start the app and it appears on the screen).  Within `onCreate` you can call something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d("FILTERME", "intent - " 
              + getIntent().getAction() + " :: " 
              + getIntent().getDataString());
    }
    ...
}
```

Now email yourself a link, e.g. http://example.com/some-end-point.

Then having the example app on your phone with a USB cable connected and adb running (I'm using android studio), view the email and click on that link and you should see the entire URI populated in the log.

Well there you go: Calling a singleton for an implicit global state in a catch-all function - not obvious at all (and IMHO a sloppy design).  Given that, there's probably a better way to do this. BTW, I figured this out [by looking at this code](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/android-tutorial-two-methods-of-passing-object-by-intent-serializableparcelable.html) ... which answered some questions that no other snippet did.

Comment: I guess u have those issues for lack of some framework basics. There's no Singleton there. The activity is created/destroyed and can also have several activities on. The manifest is a declaration of components. Every component in Android is started using an intent. Intents can have any number of extras. `getIntent()`is not a "global", it's a public method. The next activity or other components will not have reference to it.

Comment: Ok it's an inherited method. I'm not trying to be antagonistic but I'm curious as to whether you were just clarifying or also defending this approach. If you are defending this, then I'd be curious to know why you think this approach is superior to declaring a method name that gets passed the arguments ... In the same way that xlib, win32, and QT does it. Maybe it's more effective or flexible, I don't know.

Comment: And lastly, what are the names of decent design patterns for this approach to message passing? I want to learn more about this.

Comment: Mostly clarifying. But in the case of activity, it's also an appropriate approach, that's because you don't have to deal with the intent parameters during `onCreate`, you can do it at any moment of the life cycle. Also, an existing activity can have other intents deliver to it on some special cases (see `onNewIntent`) so the inherited method always give the latest `intent`. As a comparison, `Service` have a direct callback (`onStartComand`), because the service is to execute the intent as a direct command. The way you were originally imaging the activity.